# Store user session Corona SDK

Tags: php, session, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to build a social app using Lua(Corona SDK). What I want to do is save the user in a session when they login/register so they won't have to login whenever they close the app and open it again.

I am sort of confused because I don't really know much Lua but my code doesn't work. I am using PHP and MySQL as the backend and DB. I already save the user in a session in PHP but how do I show the session id to the front end and verify it so that I can automatically login in ?

```
local function networkListener( event ) 

    if ( event.isError ) then 

        local alert = native.showAlert("Error Logging In", "Check your internet connection .", {"Try again" }) 
    else if event.response == "success" then 
        -- put the code here to go to where the user needs to be -- after a successful registration 

        --username = userID

        composer.setVariable( "username", username.text ) 
        composer.gotoScene( "feed", { params = parametersToSend } ) 
        composer.removeScene( "login" )

    else -- put code here to notify the user of the problem, perhaps -- a native.alert() dialog that shows 
        --them the value of event.response -- and take them back to the registration screen to let them try 
        --again 
        local json = require("json") print( json.prettify( event ) ) 
        local alert = native.showAlert( "Error Logging In", event.response , { "Try again" } ) 
    end 
end 
end

local function userLogin(event)
    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        if emptyFields() == true then

        else

        local parameters = {}
        parameters.body = "Login=1&username=" .. username.text .. "&pw=" .. pw.text

        local URL = "http://192.168.1.37/hashmobile/process2.php"
        network.request(URL, "POST", networkListener, parameters)

        local headers = {} 

        headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
        headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"

        parameters.headers = headers

        end
    end
end
```

process2.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT pw FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd); // Binds variables to a prepared statement for result storage
$stmt->fetch(); // Fetch results from a prepared statement into the bound variables

if (password_verify($pw, $hashed_pwd)) {
       
    //session_id($_POST['user_session_id']); //starts session with given session id
    // password verified
    $_SESSION["user_session_id"] = $username;
    echo "success";
    //echo $_SESSION["user_session_id"];
    //header('Location: profile.php'); 
    //die();

} else {

    //echo 'Incorrect username or Password.';
    die('Incorrect username or Password.');
}
```

That is how I login to my app. Any help ?

Comment: in your `composer.setVariable( "username", username.text )` where is this `username` coming from?

Comment: @swadhwa `username = native.newTextField( 160, 200, 300, 30 )  -- take the local off since it's forward declared
    username.placeholder = "Username"
    scrollView:insert(username)`

Comment: session is probably not the way to do it. You could though. Basically whenever you `session_start()` at server (in your php code), it sends a cookie (session identifier) back to client and the browser stores it and sends it on subsequent http requests. I'm not sure if the http client in lua does that automatically for you, or you may have to perhaps implement that yourself.

Comment: I'd probably go with an access_token based approach, wherein you create an encrypted token (with user info in it) at the server [ after logging in the user  ], and the client ( lua based app ) has to send that token on every request to the server. server ( your php code ) must decrypt that token and get user info, that way nothing gets stored at the server.

Comment: @swadhwa but would that be sufficient enough to send messages, create posts, follow people like pictures etc ?

Comment: I'm able to get the username back how can I save that in Lua as the session identifier ?